# How to duplicate data in sql with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I havea table as table_A . table_A includes these columns

```
-CountryName
-Min_Date
-Max_Date
-Number
```

I want to duplicate data with seperating by months. For example

```
Argentina | 2015-01-04 | 2015-04-07 | 100
England   | 2015-02-08 | 2015-03-11 | 90
```

I want to see a table as this (Monthly seperated)

```
Argentina | 01-2015 | 27 //(days to end of the min_date's month)
Argentina | 02-2015 | 29 //(days full month)
Argentina | 03-2015 | 31 //(days full month)
Argentina | 04-2015 | 7  //(days from start of the max_date's month)
England   | 02-2015 | 21 //(days)
England   | 03-2015 | 11 //(days)
```

I tried too much thing to made this for each records. But now my brain is so confusing and my project is delaying.

Does anybody know how can i solve this. I tried to duplicate each rows with datediff count but it is not working

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CountryName, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(M,Min_Date ,Max_Date )+1,1) as count FROM table_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CountryName, count-1 FROM cte WHERE count>1
)
SELECT CountryName,count FROM cte
```

Comment: i removed the mysql tag as you are using cte's and i assume it is sql-server you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Generate all the dates between min and max dates for each country.

-Then get the month start and month end dates for each country,year,month.

-Finally get the date differences of the month start and month end.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Country, min_date dt,min_date,max_date FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Country, dateadd(dd,1,dt),min_date,max_date FROM cte WHERE  dt < max_date
)
,monthends as (
SELECT country,year(dt) yr,month(dt) mth,max(dt) monthend,min(dt) monthstart
FROM cte
GROUP BY country,year(dt),month(dt)) 
select country
,cast(mth as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(yr as varchar(4)) yr_month
,datediff(dd,monthstart,monthend)+1 days_diff
from monthends
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/UHXN44464)**

EDIT: Another option would be to generate all the dates once (the example shown here generates 51 years of dates from 2000 to 2050) and then joining it to the table to get the days by month.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cast('2000-01-01' as date) dt,cast('2050-12-31' as date) maxdt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(dd,1,dt),maxdt FROM cte WHERE  dt < maxdt
)    
SELECT country,year(dt) yr,month(dt) mth, datediff(dd,min(dt),max(dt))+1 days_diff
FROM cte c
JOIN t on c.dt BETWEEN t.min_date and t.max_date
GROUP BY country,year(dt),month(dt)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I tried your code and first feelings are wonderful.i will compare values  .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea.  But you need to construct the months:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT CountryName, Min_Date as dte, Min_Date, Max_Date
      FROM table_A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CountryName, DATEADD(month, 1, dte), Min_Date, Max_Date
      FROM cte
      WHERE dte < Max_date
     )
SELECT CountryName, dte
FROM cte;
```

Getting the number of days in the month is a bit more complicated.  That requires some thought.

Oh, I forgot about `EOMONTH()`:

```
select countryName, dte,
       (case when dte = min_date
             then datediff(day, min_date, eomonth(dte)) + 1
             when dte = max_date
             then day(dte)
             else day(eomonth(dte))
        end) as days
from cte;
```

Comment: just include expression `datediff(day, dte, dateadd(month, 1, dte) - 1)` in the cte ?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I am using sql server 2008 r2. So i will try to make eomonth with dateadd function. I will write the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Calendar Table makes this stuff pretty easy. RexTester: http://rextester.com/EBTIMG23993

```
begin
create table #enderaric (
  CountryName varchar(16)
  , Min_Date date
  , Max_Date date
  , Number int 
  ) 
insert into #enderaric values  
  ('Argentina' ,'2015-01-04' ,'2015-04-07' ,'100') 
, ('England' ,'2015-02-08' ,'2015-03-11' ,'90') 
end;
-- select * from #enderaric
--*/"
declare @FromDate date; 
declare @ThruDate date; 
set @FromDate = '2015-01-01';
set @ThruDate = '2015-12-31';
with x as (
  select top (cast(sqrt(datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate)) as int) + 1)
      [number] 
    from [master]..spt_values v
  )
/* Date Range CTE */
,cal as (
  select top (1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate))
        DateValue  = convert(date,dateadd(day,
          row_number() over (order by x.number)-1,@FromDate)
          )

    from x cross join x as y
      order by DateValue
  )

  select 
      e.CountryName
    , YearMonth = convert(char(7),left(convert(varchar(10),DateValue),7))
    , [Days]=count(c.DateValue)
    from #enderaric as e
      inner join cal c on c.DateValue >= e.min_date 
                      and c.DateValue <=  e.max_date
    group by
        e.CountryName
      , e.Min_Date
      , e.Max_Date
      , e.Number
      , convert(char(7),left(convert(varchar(10),DateValue),7))
```

results in:

```
CountryName      YearMonth Days
---------------- --------- -----------
Argentina        2015-01   28
Argentina        2015-02   28
Argentina        2015-03   31
Argentina        2015-04   7
England          2015-02   21
England          2015-03   11
```

More about calendar tables:

- Aaron Bertrand - Generate a set or sequence without loops

  - [generate-a-set-1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
  - [generate-a-set-2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
  - [generate-a-set-3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [David Stein - Creating a Date Table/Dimension on SQL 2008](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Michael Valentine Jones - F_TABLE_DATE](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)